# Automatically convert images in Photos.app

Tags: photos.app

In Photos.app, I have a lot of large png files that I would like to convert to jpeg files. Can I somehow convert them all automatically and keep all the metadata in the process?

Answer (score 1):

You can select all the png files in your photo and then under the File menu select Export. The top option will be to Export x items where x is the number of png files you selected. Select that option and a new pane appears where you can set the type as jpeg. See pane below.

[image]

I'm not positive this saves the metadata so I advise you to run this on one image and see if it works.